# Combine parts of an Array of Days

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I've got a tough task of displaying hours for various places. I would like to combine the instances where the hours start one evening and end the following morning. Anyone know how I might be able to modify the script below to get this to work properly?

**I have a MySQL table that looks like this:**

[image]

**My current PHP script outputs the days and times from the table like this:**

Mon - Thu:  11:00pm to 11:59pm

Mon - Thu:  12:00am to 2:00am

**I would like it to look like this:**

Mon - Thu:  11:00pm to 2:00am

**Here is my current PHP script:**

```
<?php

//connection

$day_times = array();
$days_map = array(
     'monday'     => 'Mon',
     'tuesday'    => 'Tue',
     'wednesday'  => 'Wed',
     'thursday'   => 'Thu',
     'friday'     => 'Fri',
     'saturday'   => 'Sat',
     'sunday'     => 'Sun'
);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct time_group_id, start_time, end_time 
FROM times WHERE place_id = '80' ORDER BY id ASC");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $start_time = stripslashes($row['start_time']);
    $end_time = stripslashes($row['end_time']);

    $start_time = strtotime("$start_time");
    $end_time = strtotime("$end_time");

    $day = strtolower($row['day']);

    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']][$day][] = $start_time;
    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']][$day][] = $end_time;


// within your query while loop
$day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['times'][] = $start_time;
$day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['times'][] = $end_time;
$day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['days'][]  = $day;

foreach ($day_times as $timegroup) {
    $first_day = array_shift($timegroup['days']);
    $last_day = array_pop($timegroup['days']);
    $times = $timegroup['times'];

    echo $days_map[$first_day] . ' - ' . $days_map[$last_day] . ': ';
    echo date('g:ia', min($times));
    echo ' to ';
    echo date('g:ia', max($times));     
    echo '<br />';
} 

}

?>
```

**Currently getting an output like this:**

Mon - Sat: 4:00pm to 7:00pm

Mon - Thu: 11:00pm to 11:59pm

Mon - Thu: 12:00am to 2:00am

Comment: Are there any stipulations or are you just looking for the max and min datetime? Currently they are not continuous. 23:00:00 to 23:59:00 then it skips to 00:00:00 and goes to 02:00:00. Max and min is fairly straightforward, but if there are times that need to be excluded it is a bit more tedious.

Comment: There was no need to skip from 23:59:00 to 24:00:00. I would rather it be continuous, but didn't set it up that way. Is there a better way to set it up to make it continuous?

Comment: Regular Expressions are not your friend. Avoid them when possible.

Comment: How do you know a time follows on? Should they have a matching time group id, or are you just looking for one where there is no gap at midnight and the days follow? Will times go over several days (ie, could you have Monday 23:00 - 23:59, then Tuesday 00:00 - 23:59, then Wednesday 00:00 - 02:00)?

Comment: Hi @Kickstart, a time will always follow on if it ends one day at 23:59 and begins the following day at 00:00. They will not continue for several days. They do not need to have matching group ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
i dont think this can be solved in code without rewriting your table to enable you to group results together. currently you only have time_group_id as some sort of separator. the first and second piece of code will group the results in that way, but the last one doesnt group them at all. find a rule that you can split the results between in your table then it will be easy to display them split as you want.

first:

1) stop using mysql_ built in functions, they will be removed from newer versions of PHP.

try something like this bit of dirty procedural code:

```
$day_times = array();
$days_map = array(
     'monday'     => 'Mon',
     'tuesday'    => 'Tue',
     'wednesday'  => 'Wed',
     'thursday'   => 'Thu',
     'friday'     => 'Fri',
     'saturday'   => 'Sat',
     'sunday'     => 'Sun'
);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct time_group_id, start_time, end_time 
FROM times WHERE place_id = '80' ORDER BY id ASC");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $start_time = stripslashes($row['start_time']);
    $end_time = stripslashes($row['end_time']);

    $start_time = strtotime("$start_time");
    $end_time = strtotime("$end_time");

    $day = strtolower($row['day']);

    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']][$day][] = $start_time;
    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']][$day][] = $end_time;
}
```

that should give you an array of:

```
[time_group_id] => Array(
                      'monday' => Array(
                           '1123323444',
                           '4443543644',
                           '1123323444',
                           '2332133242',
                           '9782122333',
                           '3246556444'
                       ),
                       'tuesday' => Array(
                           '1123323444',
                           '4443543644',
                           '1123323444',
                           '2332133242',
                           '9782122333',
                           '3246556444'
                       // more days and times
[time_group_id] => Array(
                      'monday' => Array(
                           '1123323444',
                           '4443543644',
                           '1123323444',
                           '2332133242',
                           '9782122333',
                           '3246556444'
                       ),
                       'tuesday' => Array(
                           '1123323444',
                           '4443543644',
                           '1123323444',
                           '2332133242',
                           '9782122333',
                           '3246556444'
                       // more days and times


foreach ($day_times as $timegroup => $days) {
    foreach ($days as $day => $times) {
    echo $day .': ';
    echo date('g:ia', min($times));
    echo ' to ';
    echo date('g:ia', max($times));     
    echo '<br />';
    } 
}
```

that will give you a start and end time for EACH day. as you want them grouped by consecutive days:

```
// within your query while loop
$day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['times'][] = $start_time
$day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['times'][] = $end_time;
$day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['days'][]  = $day;

foreach ($day_times as $timegroup) {
    $first_day = array_shift($timegroup['days']);
    $last_day = array_pop($timegroup['days']);
    $times = $timegroup['times'];

    echo $days_map[$first_day] . ' - ' . $days_map[$last_day] . ': ';
    echo date('g:ia', min($times));
    echo ' to ';
    echo date('g:ia', max($times));     
    echo '<br />';
}
```

this assumes you pull out the days in consecutive order, eg mon,tue,wed,thu.

**UPDATE:**

This whole block should be all you need:

```
$day_times = array();
$days_map = array(
  'monday'     => 'Mon',
  'tuesday'    => 'Tue',
  'wednesday'  => 'Wed',
  'thursday'   => 'Thu',
  'friday'     => 'Fri',
  'saturday'   => 'Sat',
  'sunday'     => 'Sun'
);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct time_group_id, start_time, end_time 
FROM times WHERE place_id = '80' ORDER BY id ASC");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $start_time = stripslashes($row['start_time']);
    $end_time = stripslashes($row['end_time']);

    $start_time = strtotime("$start_time");
    $end_time = strtotime("$end_time");

    $day = strtolower($row['day']);

    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['times'][] = $start_time
    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['times'][] = $end_time;
    $day_times[$row['time_group_id']]['days'][]  = $day;
}

foreach ($day_times as $timegroup) {
    $first_day = array_shift($timegroup['days']);
    $last_day = array_pop($timegroup['days']);
    $times = $timegroup['times'];

    echo $days_map[$first_day] . ' - ' . $days_map[$last_day] . ': ';
    echo date('g:ia', min($times));
    echo ' to ';
    echo date('g:ia', max($times));     
    echo '<br />';
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$day_times = array();
$days_map = array(
  'monday'     => 'Mon',
  'tuesday'    => 'Tue',
  'wednesday'  => 'Wed',
  'thursday'   => 'Thu',
  'friday'     => 'Fri',
  'saturday'   => 'Sat',
  'sunday'     => 'Sun'
);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct time_group_id, start_time, end_time, day
FROM times WHERE place_id = '80' ORDER BY id ASC");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $start_time = stripslashes($row['start_time']);
    $end_time = stripslashes($row['end_time']);

    $start_time = strtotime("$start_time");
    $end_time = strtotime("$end_time");

    $day = strtolower($row['day']);

    $day_times[] = $start_time
    $day_times[] = $end_time;
    $days[]      = $day;
}

$first_day = array_shift($days);
$last_day = array_pop($days);

echo $days_map[$first_day] . ' - ' . $days_map[$last_day] . ': ';
echo date('g:ia', min($day_times));
echo ' to ';
echo date('g:ia', max($day_times));    
echo '<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks - I am a bit confused about the [time_group_id] => Arrays... Do I need to create those, or can I skip to the foreach ($day_times as $timegroup => $days) line?

Comment: thats just giving you an idea of the structure of the array you create in your while loop, as if you var_dumped the $day_times array - so yes, ignore that. its just for clarification of the array structure.

Comment: Do I use both of the foreach statements? or just the second one that says "//within your query while loop"?

Comment: Getting close - i updated my question with the "output" at the bottom. That is what I currently see from your revised code. Any ideas on how to adjust?

Comment: add the day to your mysql query - you are not getting it from the table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26229/discussion-between-brandon-and-djjjuk)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Date and Time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functions and classes that PHP provides. It will make your life a lot easier than trying to recreate this functionality on your own.

The [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is very intelligent and takes in most any string format representing a date and time. If you will always be on a 64-bit processor or are not worried about the year 2038 [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is also very powerful.